# Bring text/line segments in Lilypond in the same vertical position

Tags: lilypond

I have many places in my Lilypond score where my line+text combination stand in different heights. I would like them to be in the same height. Here is an example:

[image]

I have defined these as:

```
dord = {\once \override TextSpanner.bound-details.right.text = # " ord "
        \once \override TextSpanner.bound-details.right.stencil-align-dir-y = #0
        \once\override Staff.TextSpanner.bound-details.right.arrow = ##t }
dspt = {\once \override TextSpanner.bound-details.right.text = # "  s.p. "
        \once \override TextSpanner.bound-details.right.stencil-align-dir-y = #0 
        \once\override Staff.TextSpanner.bound-details.right.arrow = ##t }
```

How can I force them to stay on the same y-position?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use `\new Dynamics`?  So for instance:

```
\new Staff { c''4 4 4 4 }
\new Dynamics { s4 s2.\p }
\new Staff { c'4 4 4 4 }
```

Comment: I don't see the relation of your answer to my question! In what way could using \new Dynamics solve my problem? Please elaborate more.

Comment: My answer should have probably been a comment, but @Elements in Space has given a good example.

Answer (score 2):

To get dynamics or similar markup to appear at a constant vertical position, use a `\new Dynamic` block.  Fill this with spacer rests (`s`) of the right values to get the correct horizontal position.  And attach the dynamics/markup to these spacers.
Combine the dynamic block with the regular staff block in parallel (`<< \new Dynamics {...} \new Staff {...} >>`) .

(This is particularly useful for instruments like piano that have their dynamics centred between two staves.)

```
dspt = {
    \once\override Staff.TextSpanner.bound-details.right.text = #" s.p."
    \once\override Staff.TextSpanner.bound-details.right.arrow = ##t 
}

dord = {
    \once\override Staff.TextSpanner.bound-details.right.text = #" ord"
    \once\override Staff.TextSpanner.bound-details.right.arrow = ##t
}

<<
     \new Dynamics {
        \dspt s1\startTextSpan |
        s4 s4\stopTextSpan \dord s2\startTextSpan |
        s2 s2\stopTextSpan |
    }
    \new Staff {
        r2 r4 e''8 8 |
        e''16 16 16 16 \repeat tremolo 8 {g''32} \repeat tremolo 16 {32} |
        \repeat tremolo 16 {32} c'''2 |
    }
>>
```

[image: from the above code, example showing the text spanners at the same vertical position]